# Linked List Seg Faults

Tags: c, linked-list

I'm getting a segmentation fault and I don't know where the problem is.

```
#include "stdio.h"
#include "stdlib.h"

struct node {
    int data;
    struct node *next;
    };
    struct node *head = NULL;
    struct node * curr;
    struct node * newNode;

void createList(){

    int data,n , i ;
    scanf("%d",&n);
    for (i = 0 ; i < n ;i++){
        scanf("%d",&data);
        curr = head;
        newNode = (struct node*)malloc(sizeof(struct node));
        newNode->data=data;
        newNode->next=NULL;
        if ( curr == NULL){
            head = newNode;
        }else
            while (curr->next != NULL){
                curr = curr->next;
            }
            curr->next = newNode;
    }

}

int main(int argc, char const *argv[])
{

    createList();
    return 0;
}
```

Can you please figure out where? 
The first iteration is good but when `i = 1`, there is an error.

Comment: Where does the debugger point the problem at?

Comment: [Do not cast the return value of `malloc()`](http://stackoverflow.com/a/605858/1983495).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Alignment is not enough to make a *block* of code in C ;-)

Need braces. Without which the statement `curr->next = newNode;` is outside the `else` block which is not what you want.

```
  if ( curr == NULL){
                head = newNode;
   }
   else {
                while (curr->next != NULL){
                    curr = curr->next;
                }
                curr->next = newNode;
   }
```